# Fill in values of a data frame from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I have two data frames. `df1` has some NAs in a column that I'm interested in, and `df2` has this same column but with the values I need. I want to fill those values in df1 according to the rownames (the rownames in df2 are found in df1).

For example, df1 would be something like this:

```
              Age    Gender     
Patient_1      NA     Male  # Has NA
Patient_3      30     Male
Patient_66     45     Female
Patient_10     NA     Female  # Has NA
Patient_11     67     Female
Patient_23     NA     Male  # Has NA
```

and df2 contains the same information but only for the samples that have **NA** in the age column in df1:

```
              Age    Gender
Patient_1     59      Male
Patient_10    80      Female
Patient_23    21      Male
```

Now how do I fill those Age values, from df2 to df1, for each sample?

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(df1$Age)){
  
  if(rownames(df1)[i] == rownames(df2)[i]){
    
    df1$Age[[i]] = df2$Age[[i]]
    
  }
}
```

That didn't work as it filled only a subset of the values for some reason, some values are still NA in df1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `df2` contains data for all NA rows in `df1`, you can simply index all NA rows in `df1` using the rownames of `df2` and then overwrite their `Age` values with the `df2$Age` column.

```
df1[rownames(df2), "Age"] <- df2$Age
```

Comment: In general I would [avoid](https://benwhalley.github.io/just-enough-r/rownames.html) working with row names - but if the real case is this straightforward this I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

The `dplyr` and `tibble` packages have nice functions for this. First convert to a `tibble` with [`tibble::rownames_to_column()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html). Then use [`dplyr::rows_patch()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) to replace the NA values with the corresponding values by `patient_id`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df1 |>
    rownames_to_column("patient_id") |>
    rows_patch(
        rownames_to_column(df2, "patient_id")
    )

# Matching, by = "patient_id"
#   patient_id Age Gender
# 1  Patient_1  59   Male
# 2  Patient_3  30   Male
# 3 Patient_66  45 Female
# 4 Patient_10  80 Female
# 5 Patient_11  67 Female
# 6 Patient_23  21   Male
```

Comment: This is the first time I come to know `rows_patch`. Looks very interesting :)

Comment: @Anoushiravan R: It's great, however still experimental.

Comment: Yeah it's fine though. I guess you need to perform a join here.

Comment: @harre in my 3 years of using numerous `tidyverse` functions that do basically the same thing I would say that they're practically all experimental